# Getting SOMA Ads to work in an XNA project?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna

I'm trying to add SOMA ads into an XNA project (can't use Microsoft advertising). They claim I can do this through the Communications Layer but I'm not sure what it means.

Does anyone have experience using SOMA and can shed some light on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what your looking for?

http://crosslinkedcoder.blogspot.com/2011/04/setup-windows-phone-7-apps-with-smaato.html